# Conditional Joint Probabilities

Tags: probability

So we have $f_X(x) = 2x$ and $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = \frac 1x\implies f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2$.   To find $f_Y$ I need to integrate $f_{X,Y}$, but for what bounds or am I completely wrong?

Comment: For a **systematic and painless** way to avoid this kind of head scratching sessions, simply turn to correct expressions of the densities, namely, as **functions defined on the whole space**. Here your hypotheses are that $f_X$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ by $$f_X(x)=2x\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}$$ and that $f_{X\mid Y}$ is defined on $\mathbb R^2$ by  $$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac1x\mathbf 1_{0<y<x}$$ hence the universally valid formula $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$$ yields that $f_{X,Y}$ is defined ...

Comment: ... on $\mathbb R^2$ by $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=2x\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}\cdot\frac1x\mathbf 1_{0<y<x}=2\mathbf 1_{0<y<x<1}$$ and from there, the universally valid formula $$f_Y(y)=\int_\mathbb Rf_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$$ yields that $f_Y$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ by $$f_Y(y)=\int_\mathbb R2\mathbf 1_{0<y<x<1}dx=2\mathbf 1_{0<y<1}\int_\mathbb R2\mathbf 1_{y<x<1}dx=2(1-y)\mathbf 1_{0<y<1}$$ To sum up, **always consider the densities as defined everywhere**.

Answer (score 1):

You have $x\in(0,1)$ and $y\in(0,x)$, so the support of $(X,Y)$ is the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ (the area of the triangle is $1/2$, so the pdf integrates to $1$ as it should be the case).

Then $f_Y(y)=\int_0^{1-y}f_{XY}(x,y)dx=2(1-y)$, for $0<y<1$